# Import error:DLL load failed:The specific module could not be found

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, cvzone

I am trying to execute handtracking module program,but I am getting this dll error while trying to import handtracking module

Program code:

```py
import cv2

from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

detector=HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8)

cap =cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3,1080)

cap.set(4,720)

while True:
    
   sucess,img=cap.read()
   img=detector.findHands(img) 
         
   lmlist,bboxinfo=detector.findPosition(img)
   
   cv2.imshow('video',img)
   
   cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/opencvproject/sagarmouse.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 8, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required dll to your environment? If not you may add the dll to your path and restart your working environment.

Comment: How to add DLL to the path, please explain

Comment: ibm.com/docs/en/… you may follow instructions under procedure. In the fifth step add your own dll. Hint: Googled "windows environment variables path add dll file"